# Iterate with `\foreach` over multiple variables and '\remember' one of them does not work as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm not so new to TikZ but am now trying something a little more advanced and am puzzled by the following problem. From researching solutions, I see that lots of good answers with good explanations are found on this site!

I'd like to iterate with `\foreach` over multiple variables simultaneously and `\remember` one of them to position nodes next to each other.  It doesn't work as I had expected, so I narrowed it down to how the list of values is presented to `\foreach` -- it works for 1 variable if I give a range definition with `...` and only 1 item at the beginning and end of list (1st case below).  However, it doesn't work if I spell the list items out (2nd case below).  I think I need to spell out the list items as I actually want to combine more than one variable to specify different shapes etc. of each node (see 3rd case below).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

  all rectangles next to each other:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (A) [rectangle] {};
    \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B,...,E} {
      \node (\x) [rectangle,right=of \lastx] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

  2nd and further rectangles on top of each other:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (A) [rectangle] {};
    \foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B,C,D,E} {
      \node (\x) [rectangle,right=of \lastx] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

  goal: iterate over 2 variables at the same time:

  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (A) [rectangle] {};
    \foreach \x/\y [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B/circle,C/rectangle,D/circle,E/rectangle} {
      \node (\x) [\y,right=of \lastx] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a related question ([related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30938/tikz-foreach-with-two-variables-and-the-remember-option)) but the solution uses 2 nested `\foreach` loops, where you can, of course, use the `...` notation.  However, I don't think I can use the `...` notation in my case.

I'm using PGF/TikZ 2.10 (MacTeX 2011).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post. I also embedded the image into your post. Our way of "thanking" is via up-votes, rather than including "Thanks" in our post signatures. That's just how this community rolls...

Comment: The result is correct with pgf 2.1 cvs

Comment: @Werner thanks for the quick intro as this was indeed my first post. I tried to digest the FAQ on posting but didn't read it thoroughly. Whatever makes this community "roll," it's working!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently `\lastx` is not evaluated correctly, it is always **A**. Unfortunately, I also don't know why, but here are some suggestions:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\verb! apparantly `\lastx` is not increased: !

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
\node (A) at (1,0) [rectangle] {A};
\foreach \x/\y [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B/2,C/3,D/4,E/5}
{   \node[rectangle] (\x) at (\y,0) {\lastx \x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb! you could use `\xdef` to do it yourself !

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (A) [rectangle] {};
    \xdef\lastx{A}
  \foreach \x in {B,C,D,E}
  { \node (\x) [rectangle,right=of \lastx] {};
    \xdef\lastx{\x}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb! or you could use absolute positions: !

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\multi}{1.245} 
  \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
  { \node at (\multi*\x,0) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb! this also works for multiple variables !

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\multi}{1.245} 
  \foreach \x/\shp/\clr in {1/rectangle/green,2/circle/blue,3/diamond/red,4/ellipse/yellow,5/trapezium/orange}
  { \node[shape=\shp,fill=\clr] at (\multi*\x,0) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]