# Uncover line segments of a TikZ graph in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In `beamer`, is it possible to uncover a sequence of connected line segments drawn in `tikz`? For example, in the following figure, I want to show the line segments in the third `\draw` one by one after each `--` (except the first one). Is there a way to achieve this, or is it just impossible?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
  \draw[<->,>=latex](0,10)--(0,0)--(10,0)node[below]{$Q$};
  \draw<2-> node[left]at(0,10){$P$} node[below]at(10,0);
  \draw<3->[very thick, red](0,6)--(4,6)--(4,3)--(6.67,3)--(6.67,2)--(9.33,2)--(9.33,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to use a loop; the obvious choice would be to use `\foreach` and the `remember ... as ... (initially ...)` syntax; however, after struggling for over half an hour with fruitless variations of a double-variable use of this syntax, I decided to do a manual version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw<+->[<->,>=latex] (0,10) node[left] {$P$}-- (0,0) -- (10,0) node[below]{$Q$};
\xdef\lastx{0}
\xdef\lasty{6}
\foreach \x/\y in {4/6,4/3,6.667/3,6.667/2,9.33/2,9.33/0}
{
  \draw<+->[very thick,red] (\lastx,\lasty) -- (\x,\y);
  \xdef\lastx{\x}\xdef\lasty{\y}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hehe, makes me wonder what kind of trouble that automatic solution would be. As I cant pass up a good challenge, I'll have a go at it tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what your trouble was, but `remember=` does not seem to remember anything (also see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46292/iterate-with-foreach-over-multiple-variables-and-remember-one-of-them-does/46305#46305)), I'll fiddle a little more when I get back.

Comment: @TomBombadil that was exactly the problem; `remember=` only seems to work in very specific situations, but it mostly doesn't update the `\last...` values.

Comment: Do you think this qualifies as a bug, e.g. something worth reporting to Till Tantau et al.?

Comment: @TomBombadil yes, I think that it's worth reporting this situation as a bug. Will you be willing to do it?

Comment: Sure, will do .

Comment: @TomBombadil OK; I'll be attentive to any news on this issue; thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted! And it's simple enough in this case.