# Generate multiple variants of a figure using tikz and standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, tikz-external

I use TikZ with the `standalone` document class to generate figures for a presentation using [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/), i.e. outside of LaTeX. Some of these figures undergo a few animation steps, which require little modification to the source code. I would like to automate the generation of all variants. Is there a LaTeX-only way to generate multiple output files in a single run? I have used a python script that repeatedly runs LaTeX and modifies the source in-between, but I would prefer a one-file solution. Could TikZ's externalize library help here?

Comment: Which image format is expected? PDF? PNG?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the image, either SVG or PNG. But that is an unrelated issue, and I know how to handle that. PDF output is fine as well.

Comment: Standalone has a multi-page capability (one page per image/environment).

Comment: This should be relatively straightforward in `lualatex.`  True, this use lua, but inside the latex file.

Comment: I use lualatex anyway, so an example would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Related?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214474/is-it-possible-to-use-beamers-overlay-specifications-in-other-documentclasses/214787#214787

Comment: See for example [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353503/12571) of mine. Using standalone class and compiling this kind of sources, you get a PDF with a "page" for each figure. These "pages" have a tight bounding box, so you can include them later in another document via `\includegraphics[page=n]{file.pdf}`. Or convert the pdf to gif via imagemagic, as I did to generate the animations :-)

Comment: While I will use the generated figures outside of LaTeX, generating PNGs from multipage PDFs is certainly possible in a single command, so I'd say simply having multiple `tikzpictures` in a single standalone document counts as answer (I didn't know that this works, particularly that the pages are still tight). Maybe we should close this question as a duplicate of the one linked by @JLDiaz ?