# Draw polarized light

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, plot

I was trying to draw something like that

[image]

Searching through the net to see if it already exists in tikz I came accross in [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/polarizing-microscope/) the following image which looks a lot like what I want to draw.

[image]

I also found in [our site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99369/how-to-plot-circular-polarized-electromagnetic-wave) a way to draw a circularly polarized light. I tried to combine a bit the two codes but I don't seem to be able to achieve something useful.

"My code" is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,%
    fadings,%
    shadings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1.0,
    %Option for nice arrows
    >=stealth, %
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,%
    axis/.style={thick,->},
    wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth},
    polaroid/.style={fill=black!60!white, opacity=0.3},
]
    % Colors
    \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightgreen}{green!80!black}
    \colorlet{darkred}{red!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightred}{red!80!black}

    % Frame
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(14, 0,   0) node [right] {x};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  2.5, 0) node [right] {y};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  0,   2) node [above] {z};

    \draw[thick,dashed] (-2,0,0) -- (O);

    % monochromatic incident light with electric field
    \draw[wave=blue, opacity=0.7, variable=\x, samples at={-2,-1.75,...,0}]
        plot (\x, { cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, { sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)})
        plot (\x, {-cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, {-sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)});

    \foreach \x in{-2,-1.75,...,0}{
        \draw[color=blue, opacity=0.7,->]
            (\x,0,0) -- (\x, { cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, { sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)})
            (\x,0,0) -- (\x, {-cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, {-sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)});
    }

    \filldraw[polaroid] (0,-2,-1.5) -- (0,-2,1.5) -- (0,2,1.5) -- (0,2,-1.5) -- (0,-2,-1.5)
        node[below, sloped, near end]{Polaroid};%

    %Direction of polarization
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,-1.75,-1) -- (0,-0.75,-1);

    % Electric field vectors
    \draw[wave=blue, variable=\x,samples at={0,0.25,...,6}]
        plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0)node[anchor=north]{$\vec{E}$};

    %Polarized light between polaroid and thin section
    \foreach \x in{0, 0.25,...,6}
        \draw[color=blue,->] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0);

    \draw (3,1,1) node [text width=2.5cm, text centered]{Polarized light};

    %Crystal thin section
    \begin{scope}[thick]
        \draw (6,-2,-1.5) -- (6,-2,1.5) node [above, sloped, midway]{Crystal section}
                -- (6, 2, 1.5) -- (6, 2, -1.5) -- cycle % First face
            (6,  -2, -1.5) -- (6.2, -2,-1.5)
            (6,   2, -1.5) -- (6.2,  2,-1.5)
            (6,  -2,  1.5) -- (6.2, -2, 1.5)
            (6,   2,  1.5) -- (6.2,  2, 1.5)
            (6.2,-2, -1.5) -- (6.2, -2, 1.5) -- (6.2, 2, 1.5) 
                -- (6.2, 2, -1.5) -- cycle; % Second face

        %Optical indices
        \draw[darkred, ->]       (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1, 0.26,  0.966) node [right] {$n_{g}'$}; % index 1
        \draw[darkred, dashed]   (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1,-0.26, -0.966); % index 1
        \draw[darkgreen, ->]     (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1, 0.644,-0.173) node [right] {$n_{p}'$}; % index 2
        \draw[darkgreen, dashed] (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1,-0.644, 0.173); % index 2
    \end{scope}

    %Second polarization
    \draw[polaroid]   (12, -2,  -1.5) -- (12, -2,   1.5)  %Polarizing filter
        node [above, sloped,midway] {Polaroid} -- (12, 2, 1.5) -- (12, 2, -1.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, <->] (12, -1.5,-0.5) -- (12, -1.5, 0.5); %Polarization direction

\tikzset{%
    xyz path/.style args={\x=#1; \y=#2; \z=#3; (#4)}{
        insert path={
            \foreach \step [evaluate={\x=#1; \y=#2; \z=#3;}] in {#4}{   
                -- (\x, \y, \z) } 
        }
    },
    cosine path/.style args={#1:#2}{
        xyz path={\x=cos(\step); \y=0; \z=\step/360; (#1, 5, ..., #2)},
        insert path={ coordinate (cosine path end) }
    },
    sine path/.style args={#1:#2}{
        xyz path={\x=0; \y=sin(\step); \z=\step/360; (#1, 5, ..., #2)},
        insert path={ coordinate (sine path end) }
    },
    spiral path/.style args={#1:#2}{
        xyz path={\x=cos(\step); \y=sin(\step); \z=\step/360; (#1, 5, ..., #2)},
        insert path={ coordinate (spiral path end) }
    },
    marker/.style={
        insert path={
            node [fill, circle,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#1] {}
        }
    }
}

\def\lastangle{135}
\def\cycles{5}

\foreach \cycle in {0,...,\cycles}{
    \tikzset{shift={(0, 0, \cycle)}}
    \ifnum\cycle=\cycles
        \let\endangle=\lastangle
    \else
        \def\endangle{360}
    \fi

    \draw [blue, very thick] (1, 0, 0) [spiral path={0:\endangle}];
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

How to move the circular spiral to the crystal section?

Comment: Off-topic: what's with the English-to-Greek transliterations?  Surely the Greek word for "polarized" isn't *exactly* that?  Let alone "light".

Comment: @RyanReich: You are right!!! I am writing in Greek as a main language(no XeLaTeX), so while I was struggling with the code I didn't care about what you noticed! Just for the record the greek word for `polarized` is `πολωμένο` and it's read `poloMEno` and the greek word for `light` is `φως` and it's read `fos`!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To be honest, I don't understand the spiral code to well, at lest not why switching the roles of `x` and `z` leads to strange results. So I would recommend using Tikz's `plot` operation:

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,%
    fadings,%
    shadings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-30:1cm)}, y={(30:1cm)}, z={(90:1cm)}, scale=1.0,
    %Option for nice arrows
    >=stealth, %
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,%
    axis/.style={thick,->},
    wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth},
    polaroid/.style={fill=black!60!white, opacity=0.3},
]
    % Colors
    \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightgreen}{green!80!black}
    \colorlet{darkred}{red!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightred}{red!80!black}

    % Frame
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(14, 0,   0) node [right] {x};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  2.5, 0) node [right] {y};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  0,   2) node [above] {z};

    \draw[thick,dashed] (-2,0,0) -- (O);

    % monochromatic incident light with electric field
    \draw[wave=blue, opacity=0.7, variable=\x, samples at={-2,-1.75,...,0}]
        plot (\x, { cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, { sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)})
        plot (\x, {-cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, {-sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)});

    \foreach \x in{-2,-1.75,...,0}{
        \draw[color=blue, opacity=0.7,->]
            (\x,0,0) -- (\x, { cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, { sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)})
            (\x,0,0) -- (\x, {-cos(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)}, {-sin(1.0*\x r)*sin(2.0*\x r)});
    }

    \filldraw[polaroid] (0,-2,-1.5) -- (0,-2,1.5) -- (0,2,1.5) -- (0,2,-1.5) -- (0,-2,-1.5)
        node[below, sloped, near end]{Polaroid};%

    %Direction of polarization
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,-1.75,-1) -- (0,-0.75,-1);

    % Electric field vectors
    \draw[wave=blue, variable=\x,samples at={0,0.25,...,6}]
        plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0)node[anchor=north]{$\vec{E}$};

    %Polarized light between polaroid and thin section
    \foreach \x in{0, 0.25,...,6}
        \draw[color=blue,->] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0);

    \draw (3,1,1) node [text width=2.5cm, text centered]{Polarized light};

    %Crystal thin section
    \begin{scope}[thick]
        \draw (6,-2,-1.5) -- (6,-2,1.5) node [above, sloped, midway]{Crystal section}
                -- (6, 2, 1.5) -- (6, 2, -1.5) -- cycle % First face
            (6,  -2, -1.5) -- (6.2, -2,-1.5)
            (6,   2, -1.5) -- (6.2,  2,-1.5)
            (6,  -2,  1.5) -- (6.2, -2, 1.5)
            (6,   2,  1.5) -- (6.2,  2, 1.5)
            (6.2,-2, -1.5) -- (6.2, -2, 1.5) -- (6.2, 2, 1.5) 
                -- (6.2, 2, -1.5) -- cycle; % Second face

        %Optical indices
        \draw[darkred, ->]       (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1, 0.26,  0.966) node [right] {$n_{g}'$}; % index 1
        \draw[darkred, dashed]   (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1,-0.26, -0.966); % index 1
        \draw[darkgreen, ->]     (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1, 0.644,-0.173) node [right] {$n_{p}'$}; % index 2
        \draw[darkgreen, dashed] (6.1, 0, 0) -- (6.1,-0.644, 0.173); % index 2
    \end{scope}

    %Second polarization
    \draw[polaroid]   (12, -2,  -1.5) -- (12, -2,   1.5)  %Polarizing filter
        node [above, sloped,midway] {Polaroid} -- (12, 2, 1.5) -- (12, 2, -1.5) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, <->] (12, -1.5,-0.5) -- (12, -1.5, 0.5); %Polarization direction

\draw[thick,blue] plot[domain=0:1080,smooth,samples=540] ({6+\x/180},{-1*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)});
\foreach \x in {0,45,...,1080}
{   \draw[blue,->] ({6+\x/180},{0},{0}) -- ({6+\x/180},{-1*cos(\x)},{1*sin(\x)});
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

If you want the circular part to start where the flat part ended, simply change the factors in front of the `sin` and `cos` terms to 0.5. This will however look odd, so you'll then probably have to change the angles of the coordinate axes (the parameters of the `tikzpicture`).

Also nice to see someone else is using `kerkis` ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! It realy works! It was exactly what I was trying to do! Btw, kerkis is my favorite font! That was the reason I learned about LaTeX! And when I first used it, It was the only available greek font, apart from the standard babel!!!

Comment: @Thanos: You're welcome!. Do you know the fonts of the [Greek Font Society](http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefaces20th.html)? Artemisia I use for personal correspondence, and Neohellenic I sometimes use for headings. They're all available for LaTeX!

Comment: You must be joking! I do know the Greek Font Society!  I once saw a document written in GFS neohellenic and I was really thrilled! Searching in GFS I facvoured two fonts: Neohellenic and Artemisia! I love them! But I have to use XeLaTeX in order to use them, which I don't! It is really weird to share the same taste! It's funny!!!

Comment: @Thanos: Hehe, this is really nice ;) But you don't have to use `XeLaTeX`, it works with `pfdLaTeX` as well: Here's what you have to do for [Artemisia](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsartemisia/) and for [Neohellenic](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsneohellenic/). [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) is really nice for findling a font for any occasion!

Comment: You are awesome! It works that way! Perhaps I'll ask it as a question(I was really intending to) so that future viewers will be able to see it! Thank's for this extra!

Answer (score 64):

Wasn't sure if "something like that" meant "as near to that as possible". Either way I went with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{crystal}{blue!75}

\def\zangle{-20}
\def\xangle{20}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(\xangle:0.75cm), y=(90:1cm), z=(\zangle:1.5cm),
    >=stealth, line cap=round, line join=round,
    lines/.style={gray!50, thick}, 
    axis/.style={black, thick},
    plate/.style={fill, opacity=0.875},
    markers/.style={orange, thick}]

\node [yslant=tan(\zangle), above=0.25cm, align=center,font=\small] at 
    (1,1,1.5){Left Handed \\ Circularly Polarized Light};

\draw [lines] (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,-1, 0) -- cycle;
\draw [lines] (1,0,0) \foreach \t in {0,5,...,355}{
        -- (cos \t, sin \t, 0) } -- cycle;

\draw [lines] (1,1,0) -- (1,1,3.125);
\draw [lines] (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,-1,3.125);
\draw [axis, ->] (0,0,3.125) -- (0,0,0);

\foreach \k [evaluate={%
    \i=\k*5.625; 
    \j=\i>0 ? \i-5.625 : 0; 
    \a=90-\i; 
    \b=90-\j; 
    \c=int(mod(\k,4));}] 
    in {0,...,192}{
        \ifnum\c=0
            \draw [->] (0,0,\i/360) -- ++(cos \a, sin \a, 0);
        \fi
        \draw [red] (cos \a, sin \a, \i/360) -- (cos \b, sin \b, \j/360);
    }

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,3.125)}]

\node [yslant=tan(\zangle), above=0.25cm, align=center,font=\small] at 
    (1,1,1.5){Linearly Polarized Light};

\begin{scope}[xscale=1.5, yscale=1.5]
    \path [crystal!25, plate] 
        (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,-1,0) -- cycle;
    \path [crystal!50, plate] 
        (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,-1,-0.125) -- (-1,1,-0.125) -- (-1,1, 0) -- cycle;
    \path [crystal!75, plate] 
        (-1,1,0) -- (-1,1,-0.125) -- (1,1,-0.125) -- (1,1, 0) -- cycle;
    \node [yslant=tan(\xangle), text=crystal!50, below, font=\small] at 
        (-1.125,-1,0){Quarter Wave Plate};
\end{scope}

\draw [markers] (0,1) -- (0,-1) (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
\draw [lines] (1,1,0) -- (1,1,3);
\draw [lines] (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,-1,3);

\draw [axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);

\foreach \k [evaluate={%
    \i=\k*5.625; \j=\i>0 ? \i-5.625 : 0; 
    \a=90-\i; 
    \b=90-\j; 
    \c=int(mod(\k,4)==0 && sin \a != 0); 
    \d=int(\k+1/4);}] in {0,...,192}{
    \ifodd\d
        \ifnum\c=1
            \draw [->] (0,0,\i/360) -- ++(sin \a, sin \a, 0);
        \fi
        \draw [red] (sin \a, sin \a, \i/360) -- (sin \b, sin \b, \j/360);
    \else
        \draw [red] (sin \a, sin \a, \i/360) -- (sin \b, sin \b, \j/360);
        \ifnum\c=1
            \draw [->] (0,0,\i/360) -- ++(sin \a, sin \a, 0);
        \fi
    \fi
}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,6.125)}]

\node [yslant=tan(\zangle), above=0.25cm, align=center,font=\small] at 
(1,1,1.5){Unpolarized Light};

\begin{scope}[xscale=1.5, yscale=1.5]
    \path [crystal!25, plate] 
        (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,1,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (1,-1, 0) -- cycle;
    \path [crystal!50, plate] 
        (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,-1,-0.0625) -- (-1,1,-0.0625) -- (-1,1, 0) -- 
        cycle;
    \path [crystal!75, plate] 
        (-1,1,0) -- (-1,1,-0.0625) -- (1,1,-0.0625) -- (1,1, 0) -- cycle;
    \node [yslant=tan(\xangle), text=crystal!50, below, font=\small] at 
        (-1,-1,0){Linear Polarizer};
\end{scope}

\draw [markers] (-1.25,-1.25) -- (1.25,1.25);

\draw [lines] (0,1.414,0) -- (0,1.414,2);
\draw [lines] (1.414,0,0) -- (1.414,0,3);
\draw [lines] (1,1,0) -- (1,1,1);
\draw [lines] (-1,-1,0) -- (-1,-1, 0.5);
\draw [axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);

\foreach \k [evaluate={%
    \i=\k*5.625; \j=\i>0 ? \i-5.625 : 0;
    \a=90-\i; 
    \b=90-\j; 
    \c=int((mod(\k,4)==0 && sin \a != 0) || (\k==65) || (\k==129)); 
    \d=int(\k+1/4);
    \r=(\k>64) ? 1.414 : 1;
    \xa=(\k > 64) && (\k < 129) ? 0 : sin(\a)*\r;
    \xb=(\k > 64) && (\k < 129) ? 0 : sin(\b)*\r;
    \ya=(\k < 129) ? sin(\a)*\r : 0;
    \yb=(\k < 129) ? sin(\b)*\r : 0;
    }] in {0,...,192}{
        \ifodd\d
            \ifnum\c=1
                \draw [->] (0,0,\i/360) -- ++(\xa, \ya, 0);
            \fi
            \draw [red] (\xa, \ya, \i/360) -- (\xb, \yb, 
            \j/360);
        \else
            \draw [red] (\xa, \ya, \i/360) -- (\xb, \yb, 
            \j/360);
            \ifnum\c=1
                \draw [->] (0,0,\i/360) -- ++(\xa, \ya, 0);
            \fi
        \fi
    }

\draw [ultra thick, ->] (0,0,3.5) -- (0,0,3);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! I didn't have exactly that on my mind but WOW!!! In case I haven't mentioned:WOW!!! You are awsome!

Comment: As an addendum, if one wants to have various angles for the linearly polarized light, one can use `(\cos(\angle)*sin \a, \sin(\angle)*sin \a, \i/360)` in place of `(sin \a, sin \a, \i/360)` (and nearby positions). Took me far too long to figure this out.

You may need to remove the 1.414 factor, or add it into that if you want to keep the sizes right.